# Accessing JSON object Data

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I have a page that sends a request to a RESTful web service (via php and curl). That page receives a JSON object as a response. I am trying to fill some form fields using the data that was returned. The object javascript that gets echoed onto my page looks like:

```
var obj = {
  "NPI": [
{
  "NPI": "123456789",
  "EntityType": "Individual",
  "IsSoleProprietor": "N",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "FirstName": "John",
  "MiddleName": "D",
  "NameSuffix": "JR.",
  "Credential": "MD",
  "FirstLineMailingAddress": "PO BOX 123",
  "MailingAddressCityName": "SCOTTSDALE",
  "MailingAddressStateName": "AZ",
  "MailingAddressPostalCode": "85255-0162",
  "MailingAddressCountryCode": "US",
  "MailingAddressTelephoneNumber": "888-123-4567",
  "MailingAddressFaxNumber": "888-123-4567",
  "FirstLinePracticeLocationAddress": "123 DR",
  "SecondLinePracticeLocationAddress": "#278",
  "PracticeLocationAddressCityName": "SCOTTSDALE",
  "PracticeLocationAddressStateName": "AZ",
  "PracticeLocationAddressPostalCode": "85266-2273",
  "PracticeLocationAddressCountryCode": "US",
  "PracticeLocationAddressTelephoneNumber": "888-123-4567",
  "PracticeLocationAddressFaxNumber": "888-123-4567",
  "EnumerationDate": "09/20/2006",
  "LastUpdateDate": "02/07/2011",
  "GenderCode": "M",
  "Gender": "Male",

    }
  ]
};
alert(obj.NPI.NPI);
```

What is the syntax to access these object properties. The alert statement below doesn't work (it alerts "Undefined").

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `obj.NPI[0].NPI`   this should work

the propblem is that the first NPI is an array not an object so  because of the presence of the []   so you should select which element in the array

Answer (score 0):

Your `obj.NPI` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.log(obj.NPI[0].NPI);
console.log(obj.NPI[0].EntityType);
//etc
```

Your structure is like this

```
{// Start of object
  "NPI": //First element, access it as obj.NPI
      [ // NPI is an array
        { // First element of the array is an object
           "NPI": "123456789", // Then access each element of this object using dot notation
           "EntityType": "Individual",
           ................................
```